# requests module for python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4

I need help installing the 'requests' module for Python 3.4. This is what I have tried in the Python shell:

```
>>> python -m pip install requests
     file "<stdin>", line 1
       python -m pip install requests
syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run that from command line, not inside python terminal. Example -

```
python -m pip install requests
```

Directly, without openning python first.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.

Comment: as you can tell I am a newbie in Python or coding in general.

Comment: you said I must run it in command line. what is command line and where can I find it? TY

Comment: Wherever you wrote `python` to get the python terminal.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anand, I figured out a solution for my problem.